# is it possible to override css height and width of image, with image (html) height & width tag?

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing a blog platform with som special features than the ordinary ones.
But i run into problem when i try to set the image size.

I have a file with the following css:

```
.blogBody img
{
        display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    }
```

This works as it should when users add their images to the page.

BUT! some images are smaller and doesnt look nice when it is stretched to the size of 80 percent of the page width.

So therefore i let them for each image they add, specify, if they want, HTML code for each image (automatically done with tinymce)

So.
When they add an image the html is the following:

```
<img src="....." />
```

But when they want to set the size manually the img tag becomes (tinymce):

```
<img src="......" width="..." height="...." />
```

But.
The image is still 80% of the page width!
Is it possible to let the img width override the css image width?

Thanks for your time
Mattias.

Comment: If the HTML really is `<img src="......" style="width:50px;height:45px;" />`, then the `.blogBody img` CSS in your question can't be affecting it because CSS coming from a `style` attribute has higher specificity. There must be something else causing this.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about the style in img tag. it is actually html width & hight that is applied to the img tag.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding `!important` to the inline CSS. That should force the new size to over-ride the defined CSS.

For example:

```
<img src="......" style="width:50px !important;height:45px !important;" />
```

Answer (score 4):

For overide all css, including inline style and css element style, do this:

```
* {
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

The * overide all css globally ;)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Namely: "width:auto !important". The issue was I wanted to set a max-height, which DID override (in chrome), but then the width attribute on the img element caused things to stretch. This DID override the element, thanks! The key is: not only the !important, but just as much the auto.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have the same problem as the OP. I am using the editor TinyMCE 3.5.8 and when a user uses the editor to insert a photo with certain dimensions, using the 'advimage' plugin, the photo is sized using the HTML attributes `(height="100" width="100")` as opposed to CSS style `(height:100px; width:100px;)`.

This is a known issue with TinyMCE [bug report here](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4770).

The only way that I have found to make this somewhat work for resizing images is to add the "px" suffix to the end of the HTML attributes by going into the image.js (in my setup, its found in `/path/to/tinymce/plugins/advimage/js/image.js` and edit:

```
tinymce.extend(args, {
        src : nl.src.value.replace(/ /g, '%20'),
        width : nl.width.value + "px", 
        height : nl.height.value + "px",
```

Dirty hack, I know, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, element styles override any other specified styles. CSS operates on what is known as specificality rules, where the most specific rule overrides any less specific rule's properties.

An element rule does not get more specific. Double check your markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2VCk/

Comment: *Specificity* and priority are two different things.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about the style in img tag. it is actually html width & hight that is applied to the img tag.

Comment: OK, this would not override CSS styles then. Change it to use `style=""` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width: 80% instead of width: 80%, and height: auto that way the image will  only be resized if it is larger than the available space, and the height will always be in proportion.

Answer (score 0):

```
.blogBody img
{
    height:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue